# Lost instance of my grpc in blazor webassembly when reload page

Tags: blazor, grpc, single-page-application, blazor-webassembly, .net-8.0

I have one solution project SLN in .net so, I created the reference of grpc in my blazor project for instance this in my code. All the validation, auth/login work fine I can render data in my component when user login but whenn try to refresh the application lost the connection with grpc like if the channel closed. There´s my program.cs where I added the grpc like singleton for keep live in all the execution.

Programs.cs

```
        var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);
        builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("#app");
        builder.RootComponents.Add<HeadOutlet>("head::after");

        builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress) });

        ...
        builder.Services.AddSingleton<gRPCJamLogic>();
        builder.Services.AddSingleton<GrpcHandler>();
        ...


        await builder.Build().RunAsync();
    }
}
```

}

This is the output when reload the page

Output:

```
Error in http_wasm_abort_response: TypeError: network error
Error fetching data: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Is this a problem of blazor or I do a bad implementation?